# How to keep existing Exchange in new Domain

Tags: active-directory, exchange, live-migration

I have to migrate an entire domain xyz.local to zxy.com. We will setup new AD Controllers and migrate all users with the microsoft ADMT. 
Is there a way to keep the existing Exchange Server with the mailboxes and to join it to the new domain?

Comment: You would be best served by specifying the versions of Exchange in play, and the OSes of the Exchange servers, domain controllers, and the DFL/FFL as well.

Comment: Doesn't really matter in this case, since every Exchange version is deeply tied into it's current forest.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no, you cannot migrate the Exchange servers (complete with databases/mailboxes/etc) to a new forest.

However, you *can* perform a cross-forest mailbox migration (depending upon the OSes and Exchange versions involved): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/architecture/mailbox-servers/prep-mailboxes-for-cross-forest-moves?view=exchserver-2019

Answer (score 0):

Vote for Semicolon. 
You need to perform a cross-forest migration as mentioned.

Or if there are not many mailboxes, you also could create new mailboxes directly in new exchange server of new domain, and then migrate the pst files. It is more quickly.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0848532c-ac08-4998-869a-94de7502506c/cross-forest-migration-exchange-2013-to-exchange-2016?forum=exchangesvrgeneral